# Nginx docker container hosting reactjs app on AWS EC2 - Not showing

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a docker container on an EC2 instance.

When I access my EC2 container via. ssh and run the following command to serve a simple nginx container, it works.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx
```

This allows me to exclude any issues with ports and security-groups as I see it.

---

I then tried running my own nginx container locally taken from my registry.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 imageFromRegistry
```

This would work fine as well running on

```
localhost
```

---

The error turns up when I am running the second command on my EC2 instance, it simply does not show my application.

It simply gives me this..

```
This site can't be reached example.amazonaws.com refused to connect. Try: Checking the 
connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is my Dockerfile.prod that I build my container from

```
# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY  build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Docker Inspect command on running instance

```
{"Hostname":"7fc5b93b191c","Domainname":"","User":"","AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":false,"AttachStderr":false,"ExposedPorts":{"80/tcp":{}},"Tty":false,"OpenStdin":false,"StdinOnce":false,"Env":["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","NGINX_VERSION=1.16.1","NJS_VERSION=0.3.8","PKG_RELEASE=1"],"Cmd":["nginx","-g","daemon off;"],"Image":"containerRegistry","Volumes":null,"WorkingDir":"","Entrypoint":null,"OnBuild":null,"Labels":{"maintainer":"NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"},"StopSignal":"SIGTERM"}
```

Could it be the ENV path?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read docker docs correctly to ensure correct push and pull from the registry. Turns out I was using a container with an old nginx.conf file. Honest mistake.